# Read CSV data with sql query

Tags: sql, .net, sql-server, csv

I read a csv data into a SqlDataSource. For some reason I still getting an error.

link to CSV:

https://v4p4sz5ijk.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/anbdata/states/notams/notams-list?format=csv&api_key=xxxx&locations=LEBL

TRIED:

```
BULK INSERT @TempTable FROM 'https://v4p4sz5ijk.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/anbdata/states/notams/notams-list?format=csv&api_key=xxxx&locations=LEBL' WITH (FIELDTERMINATOR = ',', ROWTERMINATOR = '\n')
```

ERROR:

> Referencia a objeto no establecida como instancia de un objeto.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add the tag for the database product you are using

Comment: The URL that you are using is not recognised, it would be better to insert the data from a csv file.

Comment: Thats all what I get provided. They dont provide me a proper csv file

Comment: Can you create a folder on the C drive called temp and then save a text file as CSV.csv in the folder? [Scag test #2 4?]

Comment: how would you do that?

Comment: Do you have 'This PC' on your computer? If so, it should show a disk drive Local Disk (C): if you double click that it should open a window and you can create a folder called temp in there, then create a csv file which you could use to bring the data in from. If you create the folder, I'll explain further.